# Javascript getTextBetweenTags function using regex

Tags: regex

I have following function into to get the text between tags but it is returing tag as well so anyone tell me whtat is wrong in regex expression.

String.prototype.getTextBetweenTags = function (tagname) {

```
var pattern = "<" + tagname + " ?.*>(.*)</" + tagname + ">";  
return this.match(pattern)[0];
```

}

return `<title>hello</title>`

should return just **Hello**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of the result is the entire string. Element 1 is the contents of the first capturing group.

Try this:

```
return this.match(pattern)[1];
```

Also, don't use regex to parse HTML. There are hundreds of ways that your regular expression could break.

Comment: can you suggest better way to do it?